# MongoDB filter documents by calculated value in range (between min and max)

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm trying to filter a collection of documents that contain birth date record, according to an age range: i.e. all documents where the birth date specifies an age that is at least larger than a given value and at least lower than a given value.

I know I can calculate "age" from "date of birth" like so:

```js
{ $dateDiff: { startDate: "$dateOfBirth", endDate: "$$NOW", unit: "year"} }
```

And I can use this in an `$expr` filter with an `$and` to check that the result satisfies both lower limit and upper limit, but what I got is this:

```js
db.people.filter({ $expr: {
  $and: [
    { $gte: [
      { $dateDiff: { startDate: "$dateOfBirth", endDate: "$$NOW", unit: "year" } },
      18
    ] },
    { $lte: [
      { $dateDiff: { startDate: "$dateOfBirth", endDate: "$$NOW", unit: "year"} },
      35
    ] }
  ]
} })
```

Which works - but it seems to me that it is redundant to calculate the age twice: there should be a way to first calculate the "virtual field" `age` and then filter on the already calculated value, instead of calculating it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can use [the `$let` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to achieve your goal. It would look as follows:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $let: {
      vars: {
        age: {
          $dateDiff: {
            startDate: "$dateOfBirth",
            endDate: "$$NOW",
            unit: "year"
          }
        }
      },
      in: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              "$$age",
              18
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              "$$age",
              35
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

See how it works in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1n5VwyZVxF6).

---

That said, I wouldn't recommend this approach if it is a frequent operation on a sizable collection. Doing it this way prevents the use of indexes which would force the full collection to be scanned. Instead, calculate the date boundaries that correspond with the ages that should match. If sticking with usage of `$$NOW` (if using a view or something), that might look like:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $gte: [
          "$dateOfBirth",
          {
            $dateSubtract: {
              startDate: "$$NOW",
              unit: "year",
              amount: 35
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        $lte: [
          "$dateOfBirth",
          {
            $dateSubtract: {
              startDate: "$$NOW",
              unit: "year",
              amount: 18
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Associated [mongoplayground is here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LK7qpMMwz-c). While I didn't add the index there, the `explain` output from a local test shows it is used as expected:

```
    winningPlan: {
      stage: 'FETCH',
      filter: {
        '$expr': {
          '$and': [
            {
              '$gte': [
                '$dateOfBirth',
                { '$const': ISODate("1988-11-12T22:46:30.785Z") }
              ]
            },
            {
              '$lte': [
                '$dateOfBirth',
                { '$const': ISODate("2005-11-12T22:46:30.785Z") }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'IXSCAN',
        keyPattern: { dateOfBirth: 1 },
        indexName: 'dateOfBirth_1',
        isMultiKey: false,
        multiKeyPaths: { dateOfBirth: [] },
        isUnique: false,
        isSparse: false,
        isPartial: false,
        indexVersion: 2,
        direction: 'forward',
        indexBounds: {
          dateOfBirth: [ '[new Date(595377990785), new Date(1131835590785)]' ]
        }
      }
    },
    rejectedPlans: []
  },
  command: {
    find: 'foo',
    filter: {
      '$expr': {
        '$and': [
          {
            '$gte': [
              '$dateOfBirth',
              {
                '$dateSubtract': { startDate: '$$NOW', unit: 'year', amount: 35 }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            '$lte': [
              '$dateOfBirth',
              {
                '$dateSubtract': { startDate: '$$NOW', unit: 'year', amount: 18 }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    '$db': 'engine'
  },
```

And if you can calculate the date client side then the query is much more readable:

```
db.collection.find({
  dateOfBirth: {
    $gte: new Date("1988-11-12"),
    $lte: new Date("2005-11-12")
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3qipUkXj9QE)

Comment: Thank you! Using cut-off dates is a much better idea, and I should have started with that. 